# Application crash when using getaddrinfo() with AI_NUMERICSERV and Service as NULL

Tags: c++, macos, networking, posix

I am running an application compiled using clang, stored on Windows 8, accessed on OSX. The application runs fine when getaddrinfo() is given any other input, but crashes if hostname other than ::1 is specified and service name is specified as NULL. Can anyone help me with this?

EDIT:

The source code is as follows:

```
addrinfo hints;
addrinfo *results;
int error;
tTestCaseInputs cases[] = {
     {"::1",  NULL},
     {"lanhostname",  NULL},
     {"facebook.com", NULL},
     {"ipv6.google.com",  NULL},
     {NULL,  NULL},     
};

tTestAddrInfo0 values[] = {
     {AI_PASSIVE | AI_NUMERICSERV,          AF_INET,    SOCK_STREAM,    IPPROTO_TCP},
};

for (long i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(values); ++ i) {
    // set hints
    for (long j = 0; j < ARRAYSIZE(cases); ++ j) {

            tTestCaseInputs *  testcase = &cases[j];

        if((error = getaddrinfo(testcase->uHost, testcase->uServ, &hints, &results)) == 0)
        {
            // Print and free results
        } else {
            // Print error
        }
    }
}
```

The source code runs fine on windows

Comment: MAC isn't an acronym... it's just Mac, or Mac OS X (actually now, it's just OS X).

Comment: Also, you haven't shown us how you are using the result of `getaddrinfo` or how you are invoking it, so it's hard to tell what's wrong.

Comment: If you specify `AI_NUMERICSERV` and service is `NULL`, the function `getaddrinfo()` should return `EAI_NONAME`. Is that what you intended?

Comment: @dreamlax, sorry for that. will edit it.

Comment: @Oswald, yes, i expect an error code